# How to change text color based on rgb and rgba background color?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change Text color based on Background (both in rgb and rgba) color.
I got to work with rgb and can't figure out rgba colors.
Here is my code-

```
var rgb = this.css('background-color');
var pattern = /^rgba?\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)(,\s*\d+\.*\d+)?\)$/;
var matches = rgb.match(pattern);
var colorValue = Math.round(((parseInt(matches[1]) * 299) + (parseInt(matches[2]) * 587) + (parseInt(matches[3]) * 114)) /1000);

if (colorValue > 125) {
    this.css('color', '#444444');
} else if (parseInt(matches[4]) < 0.5) {
    this.css('color', '#444444');
} else {
    this.css('color', 'white');
}
```

I can't figure out the error in

```
else if (parseInt(matches[4]) < 0.5) {
    this.css('color', '#444444');
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you add a `console.log(matches)` and confirm the current values before the IF?

Comment: You're using `parseInt()`... on a non-integer string value. Just think about that for a moment.

Comment: `matches[4]` contains a `,` as first char - pull `,` out of the regex group. And it will be an value between 0 and 1 - use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`

Comment: I see `matches[4]` is `", 0.75"`

Comment: Thanks all, I got my error and got it working now!

Answer (score 1):

I would advise a better RegExp: `^rgba\((\d*)\,\s?(\d*)\,\s?(\d*),\s?([01]?\.?\d*?)\)$`

We know that the Alpha value is between 0 and 1, so we can look for `0.00`, `.25`, `1`, or maybe `1.00`. Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function changeTextColor(obj) {
    var rgb = obj.css('background-color');
    var pattern;
    if (rgb.slice(0, 4) == "rgba") {
      pattern = /^rgba\((\d*)\,\s?(\d*)\,\s?(\d*),\s?([01]?\.?\d*?)\)$/;
    } else {
      pattern = /^rgb\((\d*)\,\s?(\d*)\,\s?(\d*)\)$/;
    }
    var matches = rgb.match(pattern);
    var red = parseInt(matches[1]);
    var green = parseInt(matches[2]);
    var blue = parseInt(matches[3]);
    var alpha = parseFloat(matches[4]) || -1;
    console.log(matches, red, green, blue, alpha);
    var colorValue = Math.round(((red * 299) + (green * 587) + (blue * 114)) / 1000);

    if (alpha >= 0) {
      if (alpha < 0.5) {
        console.log("RGBA", colorValue);
        obj.css('color', '#444444');
      }
    } else {
      if (colorValue > 125) {
        console.log("RGB 1", colorValue);
        obj.css('color', '#444444');
      } else {
        console.log("RGB 2", colorValue);
        obj.css('color', 'white');
      }
    }
  }

  $("button").click(function() {
    changeTextColor($("#box-1"));
    changeTextColor($("#box-2"));
  });
});
```

```css
.color {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button style="display: block;">Go</button>
<div id="box-1" class="color">
  Text 1
</div>
<div id="box-2" class="color" style="background-color: rgba(50,100,200,.25);">
  Text 2
</div>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Your RegExp will only match an RGBA color.

Comment: @Raiyan you are correct. OP did ask for both RGB and RGBA, yet his example was only RGBA, so my answer is only regarding RGBA. If OP wants to post a more complete example, I will be happy to update my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Twisty, I got it working now and posted as answer.

Comment: @Raiyan I have updated my answer with improved code.

Comment: it still have an issue with alpha value 0. Try to set the `box-2` background color `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)`. You will see the text color is light/white where it should dark

Comment: Thanks to your RegExp, it's much better than mine!

Comment: @Raiyan I followed the logic you posted in your example. If you think this answer was helpful, I hope you will upvote it and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

With help of @Patrick Roberts, @SpazzMarticus and @Twisty's comment, I got it working now.
Here is the full working code.

```
var rgb = this.css('background-color');
var pattern = /^rgba?\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)(,\s*\d+\.*\d+)?\)$/;
var matches = rgb.match(pattern);
var colorValue = Math.round(((parseInt(matches[1]) * 299) + (parseInt(matches[2]) * 587) + (parseInt(matches[3]) * 114)) /1000);

var colorOpacity = '';
if (matches[4]) {
    var colorOpacity = matches[4].replace(', ','');
}

if (colorValue > 125 || parseFloat(colorOpacity) < 0.5) {
    this.css('color', '#444444');
}
else {
    this.css('color', 'white');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution in java for andeiod base on

`https://stackoverflow.com/users/815724/peter-o`

```
 // Put this method in whichever class you deem appropriate
    // static or non-static, up to you.
    public static int getContrastColor(int colorIntValue) {
        int red = Color.red(colorIntValue);
        int green = Color.green(colorIntValue);
        int blue = Color.blue(colorIntValue);
        double lum = (((0.299 * red) + ((0.587 * green) + (0.114 * blue))));
        return lum > 186 ? 0xFF000000 : 0xFFFFFFFF;
    }

    // Usage
    // If Color is represented as HEX code:
    String colorHex = "#484588";
    int color = Color.parseColor(colorHex);

    // Or if color is Integer:
    int color = 0xFF484588;

    // Get White (0xFFFFFFFF) or Black (0xFF000000)
    int contrastColor = WhateverClass.getContrastColor(color);
```